# jboss 7, what is the subsystem xmlns for the jar in jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules\com

Tags: jboss7.x

I am following the example at http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/using-web-valves-with-jboss-7 to work with valves. Here they have placed the jar file in jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules\org folder and in standalone.xml they have given  'subsystem  xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4" ...'

Now the valve which I am working, I need to put the jar files in jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules\com, but in standalone.xml when I give ' subsystem  xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4" ... ' , jboss is not even starting and giving the following error.

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 1044
10:32:51,209 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:32:51,506 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:32:51,553 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
10:32:52,578 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] JBAS014601: Error booting the container: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configu
ration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:161) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:125) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:187) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:261) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[118,8]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4}subsystem'
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:893) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:329) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:126) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:117) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        ... 4 more
```

What is the 'subsystem  xmlns '  I need to give for the jars we put in  jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules\com directory?

If I change to urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1, I am getting the following error :

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 1044
13:02:02,752 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:02:03,049 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:02:03,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
13:02:04,232 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] JBAS014601: Error booting the container: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configu
ration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:161) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:125) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:187) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:261) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[240,4]
Message: JBAS014789: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1}valve' encountered
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.unexpectedElement(ParseUtils.java:85) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebSubsystemParser.readElement(WebSubsystemParser.java:396)
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebSubsystemParser.readElement(WebSubsystemParser.java:60)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:893) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:329) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:126) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:117) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        ... 4 more
```

The following are my standalone.xml subsystems for this:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
            <deployment-scanner name="myShipINFO" path="D:\msi_git_workspace\MSI\msi" scan-interval="5000"/>
            <deployment-scanner name="jamon" path="D:\jamonAPI" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>




 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" native="false" default-virtual-server="default-host">
            <configuration>
                <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
            </configuration>
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <valve class-name="com.jamonapi.http.JAMonTomcatValve">
            </valve>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

The following is my module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.jamonapi.http">

   <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jamon-2.79.jar"/>
    </resources>    

</module>
```

And the directory structure for my module.xml location is :

```
D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules\com\jamonapi\http\main
```

Answer (score 1):

In example Jboss 7.2 is used. In that case `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4` is fine But with Jboss7.1.0 you need to use `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0`

Change `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4` to `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0`. It should work then.

**Updated:**

You can check schema definition in `{JBOSS_HOME}\docs\schema`

Valve is not a valid attribute till `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.2`

Comment: But then I am getting different error. I have edited my question with the error.

Comment: My bad. above is correct for Jboss7.0.
For Jboss7.1.0.Final it should be `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1`. If not worked paste new exception.

Comment: Actually I tried with 1.1 too. But same error. I edited my question with standalone subsystems properties too.

Comment: But exception is still showing `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0`

Comment: For 1.0 it shows Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0}valve', for 1.1 it shows Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1}valve'. I pasted 1.0 error earlier. In order avoid the confusion, I have edited my question with 1.1 error only. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If I remove  the line <deployment-scanner name="jamon" path="D:\jamonAPI" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem> and <valve class-name="com.jamonapi.http.JAMonTomcatValve">
            </valve> then myShipINFO war is deployed properly.

Comment: Can you check if Valve if valid tag in `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1`

Comment: Sorry, how can I check it? Do you mean Syntax? I have taken that from http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/http_monitoring.html. As per their syntax, I changed to  'V' ( v capital). But same error, Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[240,4]
Message: JBAS014789: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1}Valve' encountered